# recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed / flex core dumps

Tags: android, android-source

First time android builder here. I used to do a lot of roll your own back on FreeBSD in the day. Getting back into geekdom with android.

I am trying to build android-7.0.0_r14 for the Nexus 6 NBD90Z to run under emulation.  I plan to eventually build for my actual phone and this config is pretty close. I am building on ubuntu 18.04 LTS which is newer than what the docs recommend. Maybe that is a bit adventurous.

Here is what I get when I run make.

... snip

```
build/core/base_rules.mk:316: warning: ignoring old commands for target 

out/target/product/shamu/system/lib/soundfx/libqcomvoiceprocessing.so'
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory.' 

ninja: warning: multiple rules generate out/target/product/shamu/system/etc/gps.conf. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]

[  0% 1/35600] Lex: libaidl-common <= system/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.ll

FAILED: /bin/bash -c "prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex/flex-2.5.39 -oout/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaidl-common_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp system/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.ll"

flex-2.5.39: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.

Aborted (core dumped)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

A core dump for flex was not produced in spite of the error message given.

out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaidl-common_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp  does not exist. That entire folder is empty. It would seem that something is not downloading/copying the aidl_language_l.cpp.
```

Any ideas on what I might have messed up?

I am still a little confused at the complexity of `git/repo/make/ninja/soong/lunch` to conduct a build. It is likely that I missed something obvious.

Thanks,
Jason C. Wells

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your `make` by `export LC_ALL=C make` or put the `export` in your .bashrc

Comment: export LC_ALL=C worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After I looked at this a little closer I realized the prebuilt prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex/flex-2.5.39 would dump core with no arguments.  I created a soft link to /usr/bin/flex. Compilation seems to be proceeding.

I haven't answered why the prebuilt was dumping. My goal is to compile android, not troubleshoot the tools.

Answer (score 0):

I performed Snorky's steps. I deleted my output directory for libaidl-common_intermediates. I deleted my soft link and restored the android tree version of flex. I re-ran make at the top of the local repo. The build proceeded past the error above and stopped at a new error.  It appears that Snorky's answer worked.

Doh! I'm new so S.O. didn't give credit for my upvote.